# Crop CMSampleBufferRef

Tags: ios, ciimage, cmsamplebufferref

I am trying to crop image in `CMSampleBufferRef` to a specific size. I am making 5 steps - 1. Getting `PixelBuffer` from `SampleBuffer` 2. Converting `PixelBuffer` to `CIImage` 3. Cropping `CIImage` 4. Rendering `CIImage` back to `PixelBuffer` 5. Attaching `PixelBuffer` to `SampleBuffer`. So far I am having trouble with step 4 - rendering image back to `PixelBuffer` (can not check beyond this point) nothing is rendered to buffer (I check it using same `CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer` and get NULL as a return). Would greatly appreciate any tip or help.

```
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 480);

CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:(CVPixelBufferRef)CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)]; //options: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNull null], kCIImageColorSpace, nil]];
ciImage = [ciImage imageByCroppingToRect:cropRect];    

CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer;
CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorSystemDefault, 640, 480, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, NULL, &pixelBuffer);

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, 0 );

CIContext * ciContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions: nil];
[ciContext render:ciImage toCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, 0 );

CMSampleTimingInfo sampleTime = {
    .duration = CMSampleBufferGetDuration(sampleBuffer),
    .presentationTimeStamp = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer),
    .decodeTimeStamp = CMSampleBufferGetDecodeTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)
};

CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef videoInfo = NULL;
CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateForImageBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBuffer, &videoInfo);

CMSampleBufferRef oBuf;
CMSampleBufferCreateForImageBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBuffer, true, NULL, NULL, videoInfo, &sampleTime, &oBuf);
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? I don't see a question here.

Comment: ciContext is not rendering anything in buffer. I am checking it with the same ciimage imageWithCVPixelBuffer and get NULL

Comment: Hi.  I am also stuck some where like you.
I am capturing video using AVFoundation. I need to implement zoom in teh Avcapture delegate "didOutputSampleBuffer".
Please tell me how to scale and crop a CMSampleBufferRef/CVImageBufferRef.

Comment: If you do not need to control position, feed following settings to AVAssetWriterInput and it will autocrop NSDictionary* settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: YOUR_SIZE_HERE], AVVideoWidthKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: YOUR_SIZE_HERE], AVVideoHeightKey,
                              [NSString stringWithString:AVVideoScalingModeResizeAspectFill], AVVideoScalingModeKey, // cropping
                              nil];

Comment: If you need to control the position of the crop then I guess the only way (as of iOS6) would be to crop CVImageBufferRef using CIImage methods. Not sure if something changed in iOS7, haven't had time to go through updates yet

Comment: Hi @iOS_DEV did you find the solution of your problem? I need exactly this.

Comment: I posted my answer below, or you're asking about something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I found the reason why I was having problem. Apparently I have to add kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey key when initializing pixel buffer, by creating dictionary and passing it to initializer. Here's a code if anyone stumbles upon this problem:

```
CFDictionaryRef empty; // empty value for attr value.
CFMutableDictionaryRef attrs;
empty = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, // our empty IOSurface properties dictionary
                           NULL,
                           NULL,
                           0,
                           &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                           &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
attrs = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                  1,
                                  &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                  &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

CFDictionarySetValue(attrs,
                     kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey,
                     empty);
```

Then you just have to pass this dictionary as an argument to CVPixelBufferCreate

I found this solution here: http://allmybrain.com/2011/12/08/rendering-to-a-texture-with-ios-5-texture-cache-api/