# How to Convert CIImage to CMSampleBufferRef

Tags: uiimage, avfoundation, avcapturesession, ciimage, cmsamplebufferref

I am using AVCapturesession to record video I am reciving out at didrecive sample buffer method in the form of CMSamplbufferRef.I Have Converted that to CIImage and made some some change and now I Want to convert that CIImage to CMSampleBufferRef Can Any one please help me,
I Broused a lot but I didn't found answer to this any where I hope I'll found it here.

Comment: did you find a solution?  does it work for you ?https://stackoverflow.com/a/19916522/7767664

Answer (score 2):

I take no credit, credit goes to :[Crop CMSampleBufferRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693784/crop-cmsamplebufferref)

```
CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer;
CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorSystemDefault, 640, 480, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, NULL, &pixelBuffer);

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, 0 );

CIContext * ciContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions: nil];
[ciContext render:ciImage toCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, 0 );

CMSampleTimingInfo sampleTime = {
    .duration = CMSampleBufferGetDuration(sampleBuffer),
    .presentationTimeStamp = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer),
    .decodeTimeStamp = CMSampleBufferGetDecodeTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)
};

CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef videoInfo = NULL;
CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateForImageBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBuffer, &videoInfo);

CMSampleBufferRef oBuf;
CMSampleBufferCreateForImageBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBuffer, true, NULL, NULL, videoInfo, &sampleTime, &oBuf);
```

Comment: stop using ciContext `render` to avoid much cpu took